# Unable to scrape tripadvisor with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, tripadvisor

Hello I am can see that there are many people you have successfully used the following code for scraping tripadvisor but it didn't work in my case

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
url <- "http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g189400-d206779-r838449448-Royal_Olympic-Athens_Attica.html"

reviews <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements("#REVIEWS .innerBubble")

id <- reviews %>%
  html_element(".quote a") %>%
  html_attr("id")

quote <- reviews %>%
  html_element(".quote span") %>%
  html_text()

rating <- reviews %>%
  html_element(".rating .rating_s_fill") %>%
  html_attr("alt") %>%
  gsub(" of 5 stars", "", .) %>%
  as.integer()

date <- reviews %>%
  html_element(".rating .ratingDate") %>%
  html_attr("title") %>%
  strptime("%b %d, %Y") %>%
  as.POSIXct()

review <- reviews %>%
  html_element(".entry .partial_entry") %>%
  html_text()

data.frame(id, quote, rating, date, review, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% View()
```

Do you have any ideas why it didn't work?

Comment: The website uses java-script which rvest can not execute. Furthermore, the programmatic access to this website is forbitten, see [robots.txt](https://www.tripadvisor.de/robots.txt) for details

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But there are users how state that they can do it and I am wandering if tripadvisor have changed since 2019

Comment: The website can be still used by browers having java script engine running e.g. Chrome or Firefox. You can download the html with your brower and then do `read_html` from that.

Comment: Could you be so kind to give me more detail? I use chrome but still url1 'read_html("http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g189400-d206779-r838449448-Royal_Olympic-Athens_Attica.html")' does not work. I am sorry for asking.

Comment: `read_html("local/path/file_saved_using_chrome.html")`

Answer (score 0):

After many tries what worked for me was the one below. I have not yet finished with the rest of the info. I will keep you updated.  Many thanks @danlooo

````
reviews3 <- url  %>%
  read_html("home/tripad/file_saved_using_firefox.html") 

reviews4 <- reviews3 %>% 
  html_elements("#REVIEWS .innerBubble")

review <- reviews3 %>%
  html_elements(".entry .partial_entry") %>%
  html_text()

data.frame( review, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% View()```
````